# Multiple transfers, one smart contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I have the following function in my contract:

```
 function AcceptOffer() public payable
    {
        if ( msg.sender != InstanceOwner )
        {
            revert("You are not the owner of this contract and cannot accept the offer");
        }
        if (State != StateType.OfferPlaced) {
            revert("You can only accept valid offers");
        }
        InstanceOwner.transfer(Change)
        InstanceBuyer.transfer(OfferPrice);
        State = StateType.Accepted;
    }
```

But executing it gives a function payable error. If I remove one of the transfer lines, it works. Are multiple transfers in a single contract not possible? InstanceOwner and InstanceBuyer are two different addresses.

EDIT:

Change is calculated from the diff between AskingPrice and OfferPrice. So if AskingPrice is 5 and OfferPrice is 7 then Change is 2. When I debug the transaction, it shows the variables with their expected values. Therefore I expect the transfer to be successful. The line `InstanceOwner.transfer(change)` is acting like there's no balance in the variable but there is when I inspect it.

Comment: 1. What is "a function payable error"?

Comment: 2. How exactly are you executing it?

Comment: 3. No, It IS possible. Sounds like there is simply not enough ether (less than `Change + OfferPrice1`) in the contract. Of all things, that should definitely be the first that comes to mind. How on earth did you start with "multiple transfers in a single contract not possible"???

Comment: Another option is that one of those two recipients (`InstanceOwner` and `InstanceBuyer`) is the address of a contract whose fallback function reverts when executed (or perhaps not even implemented).

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. What may be obvious for you may not be obvious for everyone. I made the assumption based on what I'm observing in my learnings. I provided an update on the post with more info.

Comment: `What may be obvious for you may not be obvious for everyone. I made the assumption based on what I'm observing in my learnings` - you are correct, I apologize for my conclusion.

Comment: All good!  no offense taken :)

Comment: InstanceOwner.transfer(Change)
; is missing

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with multiple transfers, you can do as many transfers as you want iff you supply enough gas. The following could be possible causes of error:

- Your contract must have sufficient balance (Change+OfferPrice) or your since your function is payable, you must send Change+offerPrice WEI to your contract while executing AcceptOffer function.
- You are sending sufficient gas, try increasing the gas
- If one of the InstanceOwner or InstanceBuyer is a contract address which does not accept Ether

Answer (score 1):

Multiple transfers are very much 'possible' - but you are missing `;` on the InstanceOwner.transfer(Change) line, which will throw a function payable error **given** that you are providing enough gas for the two transfers and state change.